# Segmentation fault in malloc()

Tags: c, malloc

I need to create a function which returns an array of ints. This int array should contain all values between min and max (both included).

- If min >= max a null pointer should be returned.

The question is why, when `min = -2147483468` and `max = 2147483647` (and `len` becomes `4294967296`) I get "Segmentation fault"?

My code:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   int *ft_range(int min, int max)
   {
       int         *range;
       long int    len;
       long int    i;

       range = NULL;
       if (min >= max)
           return (NULL);
       len = max - min + 1;
       if(!(range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * len)))
           return (NULL);
       i = 0;
       while (min < max)
       {
           range[i] = min;
           min++;
           i++;
       }
       range[i] = max;
       return (range);
   }


   int main(void)
   {
       int      max;
       int      min;
       long int     len;
       int      *range;
       long int     i;

       max = 2147483647;
       min = -2147483648;
       if (max != min)
           len = max - min + 1;
       else
           len = 0;
       i = 0;
       range = ft_range(min, max);
       while (i < len)
       {
           printf("%d", range[i]);
           i++;
       }
       free(range);
       return (0);
   }
```

But, if I enter `min = -2147483468` and `max = 2147483646` with `len = 4294967295` it works.

Comment: `len = max - min + 1;` --> `len = 1L + max - min;` to avoid `int` overflow when `long` is wider.  Better to use `size_t len` and `(size_t)1`.

Comment: That assumes `long int` is is larger than `int`, so it's not portable code, but it will work on the OP's system.

Comment: Tried both, neither worked, sorry

Comment: @RaphaelRakhimov: What exactly do you mean by "neither worked"? Did both give you a segmentation fault?

Comment: First I tried 1L, doesn't work. Then I tried with size_t len and (size_t)1 - doesn't work too. Yes, both give me a seg fault

Comment: Compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. If allowed, learn to use [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: Are you sure that the segfault is occuring in the code that you are showing us? Please provide a [mre] (including the function `main`).

Comment: What is your compiler and OS? Also, make every variable `long long int`.

Comment: Did you also try `1LL` instead of `1L`, as suggested in one of the answers?

Comment: My compiler is GCC, OS is Windows, but i work with Linux subsystem

Comment: Added a main() function because I suspect there may be a bug in it too

Comment: In `main`, you are dereferencing `range` without testing beforehand whether it is `NULL`. This will probably cause a segfault if it is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you, applied some of your advices and solved the problem

Comment: @RaphaelRakhimov: Note that you can answer your own question to describe what the problem was: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Replace `min = -2147483648;` with `min = -2147483647 - 1;` to avoid UB.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica: Sorry, what means UB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` and `max` are type `int`, which is only guaranteed to be 16 bits signed (-32768, 32767), although the compiler may choose to use more bits to store the values.  Therefore, if you were to expect values ranging (-2147483468, 2147483647), these should be of type `long int`.  The program may or may not be be truncating some of the bits when you supply (-2147483468, 2147483647) or (-2147483468, 2147483646) as inputs.  This would also apply to the type for `range`.

Secondly, variable `len` is `long int` which is only guaranteed to be 32 bits signed (-2147483468, 2147483647).  Since you want to be able to store value 4294967296, this will need to be either `long long int` or `long long unsigned int`.  Even `long unsigned int` will only have a range of (0, 4294967295).  This would also apply to `i`.

Additionally,  the statement `len = max - min + 1;`, will need to include a type cast to `long long int` to avoid overflow when performing the arithmetic.  You can do it by adding `(long long int)` this way: `len = (long long int)max - min + 1;`; or if you want to be more explicit: `len = ((long long int)max - (long long int)min) + 1LL;`

To summarize:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   int *ft_range(long int min, long int max)
   {
       long int         *range;
       long long int    len;
       long long int    i;

       range = NULL;
       if (min >= max)
           return (NULL);
       len = (long long int)max - min + 1;
       if(!(range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * len)))
           return (NULL);
       i = 0;
       while (min < max)
       {
           range[i] = min;
           min++;
           i++;
       }
       range[i] = max;
       return (range);
   }
```

Side note: Range (-2147483468, 2147483647) is going to require around 16 GB of memory to be allocated, so I hope that you are ready for that.

Comment: Doesn't work. Added a main() function because I suspect there may be a bug in it too

Comment: It will not work (`malloc` will return `NULL`) if your system is not capable of allocating 16 GB of memory or if `size_T` is smaller than `long long int`.  Did you confirm that malloc is not returning `NULL`?

Comment: Thank you, applied some of your advices and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`int` overflow with `max - min + 1;`

- Use wider math for size calculations.
- Use `size_t` for allocation size and indexing
- Add more error checks.

---

```
int *ft_range(int min, int max) {
  // Add required test explicitly
  if (min >= max) {
    return NULL;
  }

  long long size = 1LL + max - min; // Use long long math
  if (size > SIZE_MAX/sizeof(int) || size < 1) {
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t usize = (size_t)size;

  int *range = malloc(sizeof *range * usize);
  if (range == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  size_t i = 0;
  while (min < max) {
    range[i] = min;
    min++;
    i++;
  }
  range[i] = max;
  return range;
}
```

Comment: My only allowed function is malloc, sry. Added a main() function because I suspect there may be a bug in it too

Comment: @RaphaelRakhimov What other function do you see in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `len` and `i` as `long long int`, added `long long int` this way:

```c
len = (long long int)max - min + 1;
```

Also I forgot to check if `malloc` returns `NULL` in `main()` function.

This is the correct version:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int *ft_range(int min, int max)
    {
        int             *range;
        long long int   len;
        long long int   i;

        range = NULL;
        if (min >= max)
            return (NULL);
        len = (long long int)max - min + 1;
        if(!(range = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * len)))
            return (NULL);
        i = 0;
        while (min < max)
        {
            range[i] = min;
            min++;
            i++;
        }
        range[i] = max;
        return (range);
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int             *range;
        int             max;
        int             min;
        long long int   len;
        long long int   i;

        max = 2147483647;
        min = -2147483648;
        len = 0;
        if (max != min)
            len = (long long int)max - min + 1;
        i = 0;
        if(!ft_range(min, max))
            return (0);
        range = ft_range(min, max);
        while (i < len)
        {
            printf("%d", range[i]);
            i++;
        }
            free(range);
            return (0);
    }
```

Comment: When `sizeof(int) * len > SIZE_MAX`, this code has problems with  `malloc(sizeof(int) * len)` leading to _undeifned behavior_ (UB).